# Flask raising 405 error when submitting a form

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have just started to learn flask but I am stuck with this 405 error

```py
# Weather App using Flask

## imports 
import main
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

## initalisation
@app.route('/')
def main_page(methods=["GET", "POST"]):
    if request.method == "POST":
        city = request.form("city")
        print(city)
    return render_template("main.html")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the main.html is

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    <p><input type="text" name="city"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

the POST is in the methods argument, but I cannot pinpoint where the error is
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the `methods` list in the view function's parameters, you should have it in the brackets that follow your decorator, like so:

```py
@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def main_page():
    # your view function
```

This will allow this route to be accessed through both GET and POST requests.